# Error Filtering graphs Power BI based in two different data tables

Tags: powerbi

I have one problem wiht the "table" graphs. For exemple:

From the table "costs" i have one cloumn called "Proyecto".

[image]

From the table "Lecturas", I also have a column called "Proyecto".

[image]

The problem is:  When I select the proyecto at the first "graph" (Alibar in this exemple), the second graph still showing all the projects. Can someone help me please?

Tried to calculate but shows incorrect values when I do that.

Comment: In order to allow cross filtering, `Proyecto` would need to be a column in another table which `costs` and `Lecturas` have a relationship to.  Is the model split up in this way or are these just two separate tables?

Comment: Two separate tables, to solve the problem I created a fact table including proyecto and created a relationship.